# Creating ZIP archive compression level (libzip)

Tags: c++, compression, libzip

I am trying to compress files using libzip and I seem to succeed but I cannot seem to figure out a way to change the compression level (zip tool supports values from 1(fastest compression speed) to 9 (smallest archive)) which I must reimplement. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

See `ZIP_CM_*` defines in `zip.h`, and `struct zip_stat` and its `comp_method` field.

Comment: zip_set_file_compression(zipArchivePtr, fileIndex, ZIP_CM_*, 0) seems to be indeed the way (where fileIndex is as retrieved from zip_file_add) but currenly only ZIP_CM_STORE produces different archive size all [ZIP_CM_SHRINK, ZIP_CM_DEFLATE] produce the archive of the same size. Thank you for pointing out that there are other flags that are not in the documentation.

Comment: It's strange. It uses zlib and I cannot believe that zlib ignores compression level. I would check if casual zip tool which uses zlib produces different archives for your data. I've only evaluated libzip, I decided to use minizip, thus I cannot check if your problem is reproducible.

Comment: minizip does use zlib and then the compression level works perfectly. libzip is a separate library and I am currently only evaluating it also. So far I am also inclined to prefer minizip.

Comment: @typical Surprisign, libzip includes zlib.h so I assumed it uses zlib. Sorry for misleading clue.